# Can not update pip on Fedora 23

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I update pip with "pip install --upgrade pip", I get a error

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
Using cached pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Hash of the package https: //pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=22db7b6a517a09c29d54a76650f170eb (from https: //pypi.python.org/simple/pip/) (1849e23763040035fbb849b56d141663) doesn't match the expected hash 22db7b6a517a09c29d54a76650f170eb!
Bad md5 hash for package https: //pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=22db7b6a517a09c29d54a76650f170eb (from https: //pypi.python.org/simple/pip/)
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or firewall that intercepts your traffic? Try downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl using a web browser to see if it downloads correctly.

Comment: Are you running `pip` from a virtualenv?